# What did Black Widow say?

Tags: dialogue, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, translation

In the film *The Avengers*, Black Widow is a Russian super-spy.  In the scene that introduces her, it ends with her receiving orders to bring in Dr. Bruce Banner.  After receiving these orders, the scene ends with her saying something in a foreign language, presumably a swear word.  What did she say, and what's the translation to English?

Comment: Do you know what she's saying before she gets the call?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As I remember she said "bozhe moi"(Боже мой) which would be "**My God**" or better put "Oh My god!" and obviously it is Russian.

To hear it pronounced [Google translate](http://translate.google.com/#ru/en/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Comment: It's also Colossus' favorite exclamation in the X-men comics

Answer (score 20):

I thought it was closer to "Боже мой" - an interjection "Oh goodness", "Oh my", or "My God" - but its the same sort of thing.

"бог"(bog) would be Russian for God, but I think she definitely says "Боже мой" (bozhe moi). Though essentially they mean the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the romanizations in your alternative, next time I see the movie I'll keep an ear out.

Comment: “Боже” is a fossilized vocative of “бог.”

Answer (score 15):

According an unofficial [script](http://www.fanfiction.net/s/8263477/4/Marvels-The-Avengers-Script) she said the following:

> Romanoff: боже мой. (Pronounced Bozhe moĭ - Russian for, 'my God'.)